# How to find attribute within class using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

So I have been trying to print the link in the "data-src" attribute not the href, below is my attempt aswell the html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "domain.org/extention/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class' : 'snap-media-link'}):
    print(i.a['data-src'])
```

Here is the html

```html
<div class="snap-media-handler">
    <a class="snap-media-link" href="domain.org/snap_item/178262/">
        <img data-expand="600" width="662" height="1016" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%1F1000%1Gsvg' viewBox%3D'0 0 662 1016'%2F%3E" data-src="domain.org/wp-content/VideoCapture_546677-44278-667x1024.jpg?x44644">
    </a>
    <!-- other results -->
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are accessing the `a` tag twice, first in the `find_all()` method through the class, and then inside the loop. You need to refer to the `a` tag first, and then to the `img` tag, which hides the attribute you want.

Comment: Also, I showed the solution in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73214896/18597245).

Answer (score 0):

`data-src` is part of the `img` tag, so you need to find that first:

```
for i in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class' : 'snap-media-link'}):
    print(i.find('img')['data-src'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`select` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and pass a `.snap-media-link img` selector into it to immediately get the results you want and access the `data-src` attribute.

Code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "domain.org/extention/"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for result in soup.select('.snap-media-link img'):
    print(result['data-src'])
```

Output:

```
domain.org/wp-content/VideoCapture_546677-44278-667x1024.jpg?x44644
```